# convert 2d array to another 2d array using the first two columns as coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array of the form:

```
[[x1, y1, z1], [x1, y2, z2], ..., [x400, y400, z16000]]
```

I want to convert it to a 2d array of the form:
`new_arr[x1][y1] = z1`

Is there a way to generate this array in numpy? (without using python loops)

Comment: What are x and y? Indices?

Comment: yes, x and y positions. (whole numbers only, although the type of the array is float since z can be a float)

Comment: `new_arr[a[:,0],a[:,1]] = a[:,2]` with `a` as the coordinates array?

Comment: works like a charm, thanks!